Can I own gold without physical possession?
There are companies, such as this one, that offer a customer the ability to buy gold bullion, in the form of bars and coins, and store and insure these bars and coins in the company’s vaults for a monthly fee. The customer will not have physical access to these bars and coins while they are located in a vault.
Would it be halal to purchase gold bars and coins and store them in this company's secure vaults, for the sole purpose of protecting oneself against inflation, even though one would not have physical access to them?
The reason I ask is because I am wondering if not having physical possession of the gold would contradict the teaching of the following hadith:

Ubida b. al-Simit (Allah be pleased with him) reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: Gold is to be paid for by gold, silver by silver, wheat by wheat, barley by barley, dates by dates, and salt by salt, like for like and equal for equal, payment being made hand to hand. If these classes differ, then sell as you wish if payment is made hand to hand.
Sahih Muslim 1587c
https://sunnah.com/muslim:1587c


In Islamic finance, it is acceptable to appoint an agent to buy and sell on your behalf; this is known as wakalah.
For online transactions such as yours (without speaking as to the specifics of the linked site), this means you are appointing the actual service provider as the wakeel, the agent who buys the gold on your behalf. This transaction still needs to be made in accordance to Islamic laws, but the whole "hand to hand" requirement is between the wakeel and the seller, so you don't need to take immediate personal physical possession yourself as long as you have full control of the goods once you purchase them (i.e. you can store/sell/deliver the gold at your discretion when the transaction is done).

Thank you for this answer. Do you have some references where I can read more on wakalah?

@mhdadk Nothing in particular, but you can google it easily enough.
